# XLOOKUP returns #N/A in Office Script

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office-scripts

I am stuck on an XLOOKUP I put into a script. I have declared my variables, etc. and the below works perfectly. What I am wanting is to tweak it so it returns Null ("") if there is no match instead of #N/A or 0. I put a "" at the end of my statement (....B3000,"") but it keeps telling me ',' expected and I just can't figure it out and am tearing my hair out.

```js
// Insert XLOOKUP statement 

WsRD.getRange("A1:A2").setFormulasLocal([["SF Case Exists"], ["=XLOOKUP(B2,'all cases-part 2'!P2:P3000,'all cases-part 2'!B2:B3000)"]]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the 4th parameter for XLOOKUP.

```js
WsRD.getRange("A1:A2").setFormulasLocal([["SF Case Exists"], ["=XLOOKUP(B2,'all cases-part 2'!P2:P3000,'all cases-part 2'!B2:B3000,\"\")"]]);
```

> https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I am embarrassed I overlooked the \"\" for that. I have been looking at my screen too long, lol.